# Monterey - How to trigger DND when mirroring screen

Tags: do-not-disturb, mirroring, focus

Unitl Monterey you could enable DND when mirroring your screen to an external monitor, via notifications -> DND -> Tick "Turn on when mirroring to TVs and projectors"

In Monterey, however, the entry for DND is gone and the Focus tab was created. Has anyone found a way to reproduce the old behavior, that the DND-Focus gets activated when mirroring to an external screen.

Comment: What about "Preferences" -> "Notifications & Focus" -> "Notifications" and on the bottom of the screen there's a checkbox called "When mirroring or sharing the display" (make it off)

Comment: Thank you ! I thought this setting was now app-specific. But I just checked and your right the selection made there is applied to all notifications

Answer (score 1):

It has been moved to "Preferences" -> "Notifications & Focus" -> "Notifications" on the bottom of the screen there's a checkbox called "When mirroring or sharing the display". In order to turn off the notifications untick that checkbox.